# An open set in $\mathbb{R^n}$ is connected if and only if it is path connected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Here is a proof I found on the internet but cannot understand a part of it which is highlighted. [image]

I hope someone can help me understand this. Thanks in advance

Comment: BTW The radius of the open ball should be denoted by a different letter, say $s$.

Comment: What I don't get is the statement for each $r∊B_r(q)$" The radius belonging to the open ball?

Comment: @Sam AH! thanks! I was wondering how this was possible

Comment: @Sam Do you think the statement saying λ to be a straightline connecting the 2 points is necessary for the proof?

Comment: Yes, Heisenberg. That's the idea. The straight line stays inside that ball.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks but I am confused again. Since U and V and open and disjoint and also its union is equal to A how can A be connected?

Comment: The conclusion is that by connectedness of $A$ either $U$ or $V$ must be empty.

Comment: To complete @JyrkiLahtonen comment, "since $U$ is not empty (it contains $p$), $V$ has to be empty and this is what we wanted to prove."

Answer (score 2):

Substitute the text in yellow and after with:

For each $s \in B_r(q)$ there is a path $\lambda$ in $A$ connecting $q$ and $s$. We can take $\lambda$ to be the straight line connecting $q$ and $s$.

The rest should be OK.